# htaccess variable 301 redirect from URL (but with odd structure)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

So I'm doing a site design and the URLS are changing.  However, the old site has a very odd URL structure that I'm finding it hard to redirect.

Basically, just needing to grab the variable from the URL, and then pass it to another page that then does the redirect.  HOWEVER, here is my issue. The old urls are NOT actually query strings.

```
/rental/house.html&ID=405313
```

Notice how it is missing the normal `?` instead of the `&` ?  Odd, right?

So currently, I have

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ID=([^&]+)($|&)
RewriteRule ^rental/house\.html$ /newredirect.cfm?id=%1 [L,R=301]
```

However, this only works IF I have the ? in the url, such as....

```
/rental/house.html?ID=405313
```

Furthermore, it's not passing the variable so I obviously have an issue there as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings behind the `?` are query string. In this case your request URI is `/rental/house.html&ID=405313` and you can check the request URI. `%1` is the backreference to `([0-9]+)`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} &ID=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/?rental/house.html /newredirect.cfm?id=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: So simple yet so awesome! Thank you Ben!